# Why PayPal API requires postcode/zipcode for Aruba?

Tags: paypal, zipcode, postal-code, aruba

As I know Aruba doesn't use postal codes: http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_Aruba%27s_postal_code

If I'm sending a shipping address (country: Aruba!) without postcode via PayPal API I get back an error back: "The specified country requires a postal code".

Is the postcode/zipcode required by mistake by PayPal?
Or has Aruba started using postcode/zipcode?

Answer (score 0):

According to Aruba's postal office there's no postal code:

http://www.postaruba.com/2.aspx

So, I guess it's PayPal's fault - maybe they haven't thought that countries without postal code exist...